# Encrypting/decrypting using AES in classic ASP (Rijndael)

Tags: encryption, asp-classic

I'm trying to use Rijndael files to encrypt using AES in classic ASP. The problem is that in their sample files, there is no encrypt/decrypt function that works. The Encrypt function provided works only with the rest of the code AND the decrypt function ONLY works if you already know what the plain text is before hand. It uses what was used in the encrypt function to decrypt. This renders it useless. I'm trying to Encrypt with salt into a database and retrieve it at a later time. How can I accomplish this in classic ASP?

Here's the original files

```
<% 
'Option Explicit
' Rijndael.asp
' Copyright 2001 Phil Fresle 
' phil@frez.co.uk 
' http://www.frez.co.uk
' Implementation of the AES Rijndael Block Cipher. Inspired by Mike Scott's
' implementation in C. Permission for free direct or derivative use is granted
' subject to compliance with any conditions that the originators of the
' algorithm place on its exploitation.
' 3-Apr-2001: Functions added to the bottom for encrypting/decrypting large
' arrays of data. The entire length of the array is inserted as the first four
' bytes onto the front of the first block of the resultant byte array before
' encryption.
' 19-Apr-2001: Thanks to Paolo Migliaccio for finding a bug with 256 bit 
' key. Problem was in the gkey function. Now properly matches NIST values.

Private m_lOnBits(30)
Private m_l2Power(30)
Private m_bytOnBits(7)
Private m_byt2Power(7)

Private m_InCo(3)

Private m_fbsub(255)
Private m_rbsub(255)
Private m_ptab(255)
Private m_ltab(255)
Private m_ftable(255)
Private m_rtable(255)
Private m_rco(29)

Private m_Nk
Private m_Nb
Private m_Nr
Private m_fi(23)
Private m_ri(23)
Private m_fkey(119)
Private m_rkey(119)

m_InCo(0) = &HB
m_InCo(1) = &HD
m_InCo(2) = &H9
m_InCo(3) = &HE

m_bytOnBits(0) = 1
m_bytOnBits(1) = 3
m_bytOnBits(2) = 7
m_bytOnBits(3) = 15
m_bytOnBits(4) = 31
m_bytOnBits(5) = 63
m_bytOnBits(6) = 127
m_bytOnBits(7) = 255

m_byt2Power(0) = 1
m_byt2Power(1) = 2
m_byt2Power(2) = 4
m_byt2Power(3) = 8
m_byt2Power(4) = 16
m_byt2Power(5) = 32
m_byt2Power(6) = 64
m_byt2Power(7) = 128

m_lOnBits(0) = 1
m_lOnBits(1) = 3
m_lOnBits(2) = 7
m_lOnBits(3) = 15
m_lOnBits(4) = 31
m_lOnBits(5) = 63
m_lOnBits(6) = 127
m_lOnBits(7) = 255
m_lOnBits(8) = 511
m_lOnBits(9) = 1023
m_lOnBits(10) = 2047
m_lOnBits(11) = 4095
m_lOnBits(12) = 8191
m_lOnBits(13) = 16383
m_lOnBits(14) = 32767
m_lOnBits(15) = 65535
m_lOnBits(16) = 131071
m_lOnBits(17) = 262143
m_lOnBits(18) = 524287
m_lOnBits(19) = 1048575
m_lOnBits(20) = 2097151
m_lOnBits(21) = 4194303
m_lOnBits(22) = 8388607
m_lOnBits(23) = 16777215
m_lOnBits(24) = 33554431
m_lOnBits(25) = 67108863
m_lOnBits(26) = 134217727
m_lOnBits(27) = 268435455
m_lOnBits(28) = 536870911
m_lOnBits(29) = 1073741823
m_lOnBits(30) = 2147483647

m_l2Power(0) = 1
m_l2Power(1) = 2
m_l2Power(2) = 4
m_l2Power(3) = 8
m_l2Power(4) = 16
m_l2Power(5) = 32
m_l2Power(6) = 64
m_l2Power(7) = 128
m_l2Power(8) = 256
m_l2Power(9) = 512
m_l2Power(10) = 1024
m_l2Power(11) = 2048
m_l2Power(12) = 4096
m_l2Power(13) = 8192
m_l2Power(14) = 16384
m_l2Power(15) = 32768
m_l2Power(16) = 65536
m_l2Power(17) = 131072
m_l2Power(18) = 262144
m_l2Power(19) = 524288
m_l2Power(20) = 1048576
m_l2Power(21) = 2097152
m_l2Power(22) = 4194304
m_l2Power(23) = 8388608
m_l2Power(24) = 16777216
m_l2Power(25) = 33554432
m_l2Power(26) = 67108864
m_l2Power(27) = 134217728
m_l2Power(28) = 268435456
m_l2Power(29) = 536870912
m_l2Power(30) = 1073741824

Private Function LShift(lValue, iShiftBits)
    If iShiftBits = 0 Then
        LShift = lValue
        Exit Function
    ElseIf iShiftBits = 31 Then
        If lValue And 1 Then
            LShift = &H80000000
        Else
            LShift = 0
        End If
        Exit Function
    ElseIf iShiftBits < 0 Or iShiftBits > 31 Then
        Err.Raise 6
    End If

    If (lValue And m_l2Power(31 - iShiftBits)) Then
        LShift = ((lValue And m_lOnBits(31 - (iShiftBits + 1))) * m_l2Power(iShiftBits)) Or &H80000000
    Else
        LShift = ((lValue And m_lOnBits(31 - iShiftBits)) * m_l2Power(iShiftBits))
    End If
End Function

Private Function RShift(lValue, iShiftBits)
    If iShiftBits = 0 Then
        RShift = lValue
        Exit Function
    ElseIf iShiftBits = 31 Then
        If lValue And &H80000000 Then
            RShift = 1
        Else
            RShift = 0
        End If
        Exit Function
    ElseIf iShiftBits < 0 Or iShiftBits > 31 Then
        Err.Raise 6
    End If

    RShift = (lValue And &H7FFFFFFE) \ m_l2Power(iShiftBits)

    If (lValue And &H80000000) Then
        RShift = (RShift Or (&H40000000 \ m_l2Power(iShiftBits - 1)))
    End If
End Function

Private Function LShiftByte(bytValue, bytShiftBits)
    If bytShiftBits = 0 Then
        LShiftByte = bytValue
        Exit Function
    ElseIf bytShiftBits = 7 Then
        If bytValue And 1 Then
            LShiftByte = &H80
        Else
            LShiftByte = 0
        End If
        Exit Function
    ElseIf bytShiftBits < 0 Or bytShiftBits > 7 Then
        Err.Raise 6
    End If

    LShiftByte = ((bytValue And m_bytOnBits(7 - bytShiftBits)) * m_byt2Power(bytShiftBits))
End Function

Private Function RShiftByte(bytValue, bytShiftBits)
    If bytShiftBits = 0 Then
        RShiftByte = bytValue
        Exit Function
    ElseIf bytShiftBits = 7 Then
        If bytValue And &H80 Then
            RShiftByte = 1
        Else
            RShiftByte = 0
        End If
        Exit Function
    ElseIf bytShiftBits < 0 Or bytShiftBits > 7 Then
        Err.Raise 6
    End If

    RShiftByte = bytValue \ m_byt2Power(bytShiftBits)
End Function

Private Function RotateLeft(lValue, iShiftBits)
    RotateLeft = LShift(lValue, iShiftBits) Or RShift(lValue, (32 - iShiftBits))
End Function

Private Function RotateLeftByte(bytValue, bytShiftBits)
    RotateLeftByte = LShiftByte(bytValue, bytShiftBits) Or RShiftByte(bytValue, (8 - bytShiftBits))
End Function

Private Function Pack(b())
    Dim lCount
    Dim lTemp

    For lCount = 0 To 3
        lTemp = b(lCount)
        Pack = Pack Or LShift(lTemp, (lCount * 8))
    Next
End Function

Private Function PackFrom(b(), k)
    Dim lCount
    Dim lTemp

    For lCount = 0 To 3
        lTemp = b(lCount + k)
        PackFrom = PackFrom Or LShift(lTemp, (lCount * 8))
    Next
End Function

Private Sub Unpack(a, b())
    b(0) = a And m_lOnBits(7)
    b(1) = RShift(a, 8) And m_lOnBits(7)
    b(2) = RShift(a, 16) And m_lOnBits(7)
    b(3) = RShift(a, 24) And m_lOnBits(7)
End Sub

Private Sub UnpackFrom(a, b(), k)
    b(0 + k) = a And m_lOnBits(7)
    b(1 + k) = RShift(a, 8) And m_lOnBits(7)
    b(2 + k) = RShift(a, 16) And m_lOnBits(7)
    b(3 + k) = RShift(a, 24) And m_lOnBits(7)
End Sub

Private Function xtime(a)
    Dim b

    If (a And &H80) Then
        b = &H1B
    Else
        b = 0
    End If

    xtime = LShiftByte(a, 1)
    xtime = xtime Xor b
End Function

Private Function bmul(x, y)
    If x <> 0 And y <> 0 Then
        bmul = m_ptab((CLng(m_ltab(x)) + CLng(m_ltab(y))) Mod 255)
    Else
        bmul = 0
    End If
End Function

Private Function SubByte(a)
    Dim b(3)

    Unpack a, b
    b(0) = m_fbsub(b(0))
    b(1) = m_fbsub(b(1))
    b(2) = m_fbsub(b(2))
    b(3) = m_fbsub(b(3))

    SubByte = Pack(b)
End Function

Private Function product(x, y)
    Dim xb(3)
    Dim yb(3)

    Unpack x, xb
    Unpack y, yb
    product = bmul(xb(0), yb(0)) Xor bmul(xb(1), yb(1)) Xor bmul(xb(2), yb(2)) Xor bmul(xb(3), yb(3))
End Function

Private Function InvMixCol(x)
    Dim y
    Dim m
    Dim b(3)

    m = Pack(m_InCo)
    b(3) = product(m, x)
    m = RotateLeft(m, 24)
    b(2) = product(m, x)
    m = RotateLeft(m, 24)
    b(1) = product(m, x)
    m = RotateLeft(m, 24)
    b(0) = product(m, x)
    y = Pack(b)

    InvMixCol = y
End Function

Private Function ByteSub(x)
    Dim y
    Dim z

    z = x
    y = m_ptab(255 - m_ltab(z))
    z = y
    z = RotateLeftByte(z, 1)
    y = y Xor z
    z = RotateLeftByte(z, 1)
    y = y Xor z
    z = RotateLeftByte(z, 1)
    y = y Xor z
    z = RotateLeftByte(z, 1)
    y = y Xor z
    y = y Xor &H63

    ByteSub = y
End Function

Public Sub gentables()
    Dim i
    Dim y
    Dim b(3)
    Dim ib

    m_ltab(0) = 0
    m_ptab(0) = 1
    m_ltab(1) = 0
    m_ptab(1) = 3
    m_ltab(3) = 1

    For i = 2 To 255
        m_ptab(i) = m_ptab(i - 1) Xor xtime(m_ptab(i - 1))
        m_ltab(m_ptab(i)) = i
    Next

    m_fbsub(0) = &H63
    m_rbsub(&H63) = 0

    For i = 1 To 255
        ib = i
        y = ByteSub(ib)
        m_fbsub(i) = y
        m_rbsub(y) = i
    Next

    y = 1
    For i = 0 To 29
        m_rco(i) = y
        y = xtime(y)
    Next

    For i = 0 To 255
        y = m_fbsub(i)
        b(3) = y Xor xtime(y)
        b(2) = y
        b(1) = y
        b(0) = xtime(y)
        m_ftable(i) = Pack(b)

        y = m_rbsub(i)
        b(3) = bmul(m_InCo(0), y)
        b(2) = bmul(m_InCo(1), y)
        b(1) = bmul(m_InCo(2), y)
        b(0) = bmul(m_InCo(3), y)
        m_rtable(i) = Pack(b)
    Next
End Sub

Public Sub gkey(nb, nk, key())                
    Dim i
    Dim j
    Dim k
    Dim m
    Dim N
    Dim C1
    Dim C2
    Dim C3
    Dim CipherKey(7)

    m_Nb = nb
    m_Nk = nk

    If m_Nb >= m_Nk Then
        m_Nr = 6 + m_Nb
    Else
        m_Nr = 6 + m_Nk
    End If

    C1 = 1
    If m_Nb < 8 Then
        C2 = 2
        C3 = 3
    Else
        C2 = 3
        C3 = 4
    End If

    For j = 0 To nb - 1
        m = j * 3

        m_fi(m) = (j + C1) Mod nb
        m_fi(m + 1) = (j + C2) Mod nb
        m_fi(m + 2) = (j + C3) Mod nb
        m_ri(m) = (nb + j - C1) Mod nb
        m_ri(m + 1) = (nb + j - C2) Mod nb
        m_ri(m + 2) = (nb + j - C3) Mod nb
    Next

    N = m_Nb * (m_Nr + 1)

    For i = 0 To m_Nk - 1
        j = i * 4
        CipherKey(i) = PackFrom(key, j)
    Next

    For i = 0 To m_Nk - 1
        m_fkey(i) = CipherKey(i)
    Next

    j = m_Nk
    k = 0
    Do While j < N
        m_fkey(j) = m_fkey(j - m_Nk) Xor _
            SubByte(RotateLeft(m_fkey(j - 1), 24)) Xor m_rco(k)
        If m_Nk <= 6 Then
            i = 1
            Do While i < m_Nk And (i + j) < N
                m_fkey(i + j) = m_fkey(i + j - m_Nk) Xor _
                    m_fkey(i + j - 1)
                i = i + 1
            Loop
        Else
            i = 1
            Do While i < 4 And (i + j) < N
                m_fkey(i + j) = m_fkey(i + j - m_Nk) Xor _
                    m_fkey(i + j - 1)
                i = i + 1
            Loop
            If j + 4 < N Then
                m_fkey(j + 4) = m_fkey(j + 4 - m_Nk) Xor _
                    SubByte(m_fkey(j + 3))
            End If
            i = 5
            Do While i < m_Nk And (i + j) < N
                m_fkey(i + j) = m_fkey(i + j - m_Nk) Xor _
                    m_fkey(i + j - 1)
                i = i + 1
            Loop
        End If

        j = j + m_Nk
        k = k + 1
    Loop

    For j = 0 To m_Nb - 1
        m_rkey(j + N - nb) = m_fkey(j)
    Next

    i = m_Nb
    Do While i < N - m_Nb
        k = N - m_Nb - i
        For j = 0 To m_Nb - 1
            m_rkey(k + j) = InvMixCol(m_fkey(i + j))
        Next
        i = i + m_Nb
    Loop

    j = N - m_Nb
    Do While j < N
        m_rkey(j - N + m_Nb) = m_fkey(j)
        j = j + 1
    Loop
End Sub

Public Sub encrypt(buff())
    Dim i
    Dim j
    Dim k
    Dim m
    Dim a(7)
    Dim b(7)
    Dim x
    Dim y
    Dim t

    For i = 0 To m_Nb - 1
        j = i * 4

        a(i) = PackFrom(buff, j)
        a(i) = a(i) Xor m_fkey(i)
    Next

    k = m_Nb
    x = a
    y = b

    For i = 1 To m_Nr - 1
        For j = 0 To m_Nb - 1
            m = j * 3
            y(j) = m_fkey(k) Xor m_ftable(x(j) And m_lOnBits(7)) Xor _
                RotateLeft(m_ftable(RShift(x(m_fi(m)), 8) And m_lOnBits(7)), 8) Xor _
                RotateLeft(m_ftable(RShift(x(m_fi(m + 1)), 16) And m_lOnBits(7)), 16) Xor _
                RotateLeft(m_ftable(RShift(x(m_fi(m + 2)), 24) And m_lOnBits(7)), 24)
            k = k + 1
        Next
        t = x
        x = y
        y = t
    Next

    For j = 0 To m_Nb - 1
        m = j * 3
        y(j) = m_fkey(k) Xor m_fbsub(x(j) And m_lOnBits(7)) Xor _
            RotateLeft(m_fbsub(RShift(x(m_fi(m)), 8) And m_lOnBits(7)), 8) Xor _
            RotateLeft(m_fbsub(RShift(x(m_fi(m + 1)), 16) And m_lOnBits(7)), 16) Xor _
            RotateLeft(m_fbsub(RShift(x(m_fi(m + 2)), 24) And m_lOnBits(7)), 24)
        k = k + 1
    Next

    For i = 0 To m_Nb - 1
        j = i * 4
        UnpackFrom y(i), buff, j
        x(i) = 0
        y(i) = 0
    Next
End Sub

Public Sub decrypt(buff())
    Dim i
    Dim j
    Dim k
    Dim m
    Dim a(7)
    Dim b(7)
    Dim x
    Dim y
    Dim t

    For i = 0 To m_Nb - 1
        j = i * 4
        a(i) = PackFrom(buff, j)
        a(i) = a(i) Xor m_rkey(i)
    Next

    k = m_Nb
    x = a
    y = b

    For i = 1 To m_Nr - 1
        For j = 0 To m_Nb - 1
            m = j * 3
            y(j) = m_rkey(k) Xor m_rtable(x(j) And m_lOnBits(7)) Xor _
                RotateLeft(m_rtable(RShift(x(m_ri(m)), 8) And m_lOnBits(7)), 8) Xor _
                RotateLeft(m_rtable(RShift(x(m_ri(m + 1)), 16) And m_lOnBits(7)), 16) Xor _
                RotateLeft(m_rtable(RShift(x(m_ri(m + 2)), 24) And m_lOnBits(7)), 24)
            k = k + 1
        Next
        t = x
        x = y
        y = t
    Next

    For j = 0 To m_Nb - 1
        m = j * 3

        y(j) = m_rkey(k) Xor m_rbsub(x(j) And m_lOnBits(7)) Xor _
            RotateLeft(m_rbsub(RShift(x(m_ri(m)), 8) And m_lOnBits(7)), 8) Xor _
            RotateLeft(m_rbsub(RShift(x(m_ri(m + 1)), 16) And m_lOnBits(7)), 16) Xor _
            RotateLeft(m_rbsub(RShift(x(m_ri(m + 2)), 24) And m_lOnBits(7)), 24)
        k = k + 1
    Next

    For i = 0 To m_Nb - 1
        j = i * 4

        UnpackFrom y(i), buff, j
        x(i) = 0
        y(i) = 0
    Next
End Sub

Private Function IsInitialized(vArray)
    On Error Resume Next

    IsInitialized = IsNumeric(UBound(vArray))
End Function

Private Sub CopyBytesASP(bytDest, lDestStart, bytSource(), lSourceStart, lLength)
    Dim lCount

    lCount = 0
    Do
        bytDest(lDestStart + lCount) = bytSource(lSourceStart + lCount)
        lCount = lCount + 1
    Loop Until lCount = lLength
End Sub

Public Function EncryptData(bytMessage, bytPassword)
    Dim bytKey(31)
    Dim bytIn()
    Dim bytOut()
    Dim bytTemp(31)
    Dim lCount
    Dim lLength
    Dim lEncodedLength
    Dim bytLen(3)
    Dim lPosition

    If Not IsInitialized(bytMessage) Then
        Exit Function
    End If
    If Not IsInitialized(bytPassword) Then
        Exit Function
    End If

    For lCount = 0 To UBound(bytPassword)
        bytKey(lCount) = bytPassword(lCount)
        If lCount = 31 Then
            Exit For
        End If
    Next

    gentables
    gkey 8, 8, bytKey

    lLength = UBound(bytMessage) + 1
    lEncodedLength = lLength + 4

    If lEncodedLength Mod 32 <> 0 Then
        lEncodedLength = lEncodedLength + 32 - (lEncodedLength Mod 32)
    End If
    ReDim bytIn(lEncodedLength - 1)
    ReDim bytOut(lEncodedLength - 1)

    Unpack lLength, bytIn
    CopyBytesASP bytIn, 4, bytMessage, 0, lLength

    For lCount = 0 To lEncodedLength - 1 Step 32
        CopyBytesASP bytTemp, 0, bytIn, lCount, 32
        Encrypt bytTemp
        CopyBytesASP bytOut, lCount, bytTemp, 0, 32
    Next

    EncryptData = bytOut
End Function

Public Function DecryptData(bytIn, bytPassword)
    Dim bytMessage()
    Dim bytKey(31)
    Dim bytOut()
    Dim bytTemp(31)
    Dim lCount
    Dim lLength
    Dim lEncodedLength
    Dim bytLen(3)
    Dim lPosition

    If Not IsInitialized(bytIn) Then
        Exit Function
    End If
    If Not IsInitialized(bytPassword) Then
        Exit Function
    End If

    lEncodedLength = UBound(bytIn) + 1

    If lEncodedLength Mod 32 <> 0 Then
        Exit Function
    End If

    For lCount = 0 To UBound(bytPassword)
        bytKey(lCount) = bytPassword(lCount)
        If lCount = 31 Then
            Exit For
        End If
    Next

    gentables
    gkey 8, 8, bytKey

    ReDim bytOut(lEncodedLength - 1)

    For lCount = 0 To lEncodedLength - 1 Step 32
        CopyBytesASP bytTemp, 0, bytIn, lCount, 32
        Decrypt bytTemp
        CopyBytesASP bytOut, lCount, bytTemp, 0, 32
    Next

    lLength = Pack(bytOut)

    If lLength > lEncodedLength - 4 Then
        Exit Function
    End If

    ReDim bytMessage(lLength - 1)
    CopyBytesASP bytMessage, 0, bytOut, 4, lLength

    DecryptData = bytMessage
End Function
%>
```

Test file:

```
<HTML>
<%
' This VBScript ASP file tests the accompanying rijndael.asp for
' encryption using the Rijndael AES block cipher algorithm
%>
<!--#include file="rijndael.asp"-->
<%
    Dim i
    Dim nb
    Dim nk
    Dim key(31)
    Dim block(31)
    Dim sTemp
    Dim sPlain
    Dim sPassword
    Dim bytIn()
    Dim bytPassword()
    Dim lCount

    gentables

    For i = 0 To 31
        key(i) = 0
    Next

    key(0) = 1

    For i = 0 To 31
        block(i) = i
    Next

    For nb = 4 To 8 Step 2
        For nk = 4 To 8 Step 2

            gkey nb, nk, key
            Response.Write "Block Size=" & nb * 32 & ",  Key size=" & nk * 32 & "<BR>"

            Response.Write "Plain<BR>"
            sTemp = ""
            For i = 0 To (nb * 4) - 1
                sTemp = sTemp & Right("0" & Hex(block(i)), 2)
            Next
            Response.Write sTemp & "<BR>"

            encrypt block
            Response.Write "Encrypt<BR>"
            sTemp = ""
            For i = 0 To (nb * 4) - 1
                sTemp = sTemp & Right("0" & Hex(block(i)), 2)
            Next
            Response.Write sTemp & "<BR>"

            decrypt block
            sTemp = ""
            Response.Write "Decrypt<BR>"
            For i = 0 To (nb * 4) - 1
                sTemp = sTemp & Right("0" & Hex(block(i)), 2)
            Next
            Response.Write sTemp & "<BR>"
            Response.Write "<BR>"
        Next
    Next

    Response.Write "<BR>"
    Response.Write "<BR>"

    sPlain = "Plain text"
    sPassword = "Key"

    Response.Write "Message=" & sPlain & "<BR>"
    Response.Write "Key=" & sPassword & "<BR>"

    lLength = Len(sPlain)
    ReDim bytIn(lLength-1)
    For lCount = 1 To lLength
        bytIn(lCount-1)=CByte(AscB(Mid(sPlain,lCount,1)))
    Next
    lLength = Len(sPassword)
    ReDim bytPassword(lLength-1)
    For lCount = 1 To lLength
        bytPassword(lCount-1)=CByte(AscB(Mid(sPassword,lCount,1)))
    Next

    bytOut = EncryptData(bytIn, bytPassword)

    sTemp = ""
    For lCount = 0 To UBound(bytOut)
        sTemp = sTemp & Right("0" & Hex(bytOut(lCount)), 2)
    Next
    Response.Write "Encrypted=" & sTemp & "<BR>"

    bytClear = DecryptData(bytOut, bytPassword)

    lLength = UBound(bytClear) + 1
    sTemp = ""
    For lCount = 0 To lLength - 1
        sTemp = sTemp & Chr(bytClear(lCount))
    Next
    Response.Write "Decrypted=" & sTemp & "<BR>"

    Response.Write "<BR>"
%>
</HTML>
```

Keep in mind, this is using classic asp. I've tried using the DecryptData function but that doesn't work

```
decryptedText = DecryptData("1232","23423")
```

I tried breaking down the Encryption function into it's own function BUT again, if I want to decrypt, it needs info from the Encryption function, so, in other words, it needs to know the unencryped content.

```
function getEncryption(sPlain,sPassword)

    lLength = Len(sPlain)
    ReDim bytIn(lLength-1)
    For lCount = 1 To lLength
        bytIn(lCount-1)=CByte(AscB(Mid(sPlain,lCount,1)))
    Next
    lLength = Len(sPassword)
    ReDim bytPassword(lLength-1)
    For lCount = 1 To lLength
        bytPassword(lCount-1)=CByte(AscB(Mid(sPassword,lCount,1)))
    Next

    bytOut = EncryptData(bytIn, bytPassword)

    sTemp = ""
    For lCount = 0 To UBound(bytOut)
        sTemp = sTemp & Right("0" & Hex(bytOut(lCount)), 2)
    Next

        getEncryption = sTemp

end function
```

Decrypt:

```
'bytOut is part of the encrypt function
bytClear = DecryptData(bytOut, bytPassword)

lLength = UBound(bytClear) + 1
sTemp = ""
For lCount = 0 To lLength - 1
    sTemp = sTemp & Chr(bytClear(lCount))
Next
```

Comment: Uhhhhh the fact that there is an actual implementation of AES in the code base is just all levels of wrong.  In saying that, there are a massive number of examples of how to use classes like `AesManaged` to achieve your desired result.  Can you explain why none of those examples helped you?  Post some code that you tried and explain why it didn't work.

Comment: updated the original post. not much different than what i stated though.

Comment: If you are storing passwords, you should not be encrypting, you should be using  one way hashing, which means it can't be decrypted.  To verify the password you re-hash the users input using the same salt and compare the hash strings.

Comment: I am storing passwords... for which i am hashing. This isn't for passwords.. it's for sensitive information that needs to be stored in the database and restored on the website in another area. It's basically for Authorize.Net.... using the API Keys. I need to make sure they are encrypted in the db and then when I need to use them for processing, i need to decrypt them.

Comment: What database are you using? Most have built in AES encryption functions

Comment: microsoft sql server 2008

Comment: I believe you can use the `ENCRYPTBYKEY` / `DECRYPTBYKEY` functions to perform AES encryption in SQL server 2008.

Answer (score -1):

The decryption flow begins at a state which is the same as if an encryption run was just performed. But this doesn't need an encryption run to actually have been performed, you just need to advance the original state and key the relevant number of rounds to get the starting values for decryption.

In particular, the decryption round constant begins at &H36 (for AES128) instead of &H01 and is divided by 2 each round (modulo &H11B). The decryption key begins at the value after the correct number of encryption rounds (10 rounds for AES128), so it can be computed by running the key advance 10 times before starting decryption. The decryption key is 'decreased' each round, so it will use the plaintext key on the final round instead of the first.

To simplify during testing, you could use pre-computed S- and Si-boxes, which are given in the links below.

These application notes give a good explanation of the algorithms, although in C:

http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/AppNotes/00821a.pdf

http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/Appnotes/AN1044a.pdf

http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/AppNotes/00002462B.pdf